# Executing Quiet Install with Python throws dialog

Tags: python, windows

I have a `command` to execute Acrobat installation

```sh
.\Acrobat.exe /sAll /rs /l /msi"/qb-! /norestart ALLUSERS=1 EULA_ACCEPT=YES SUPPRESS_APP_LAUNCH=YES"
```

It works nice, but when I'm trying to execute command above with Python's `os` module or `subprocess` module I'm just getting popup window of usage like on screenshot. How could I call the command above from Python? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use list form of invocation:

```
subprocess.Popen(
    [
        '.\Acrobat.exe', '/sAll', '/rs', '/l'
        , "/msi'/qb-! /norestart ALLUSERS=1 EULA_ACCEPT=YES SUPPRESS_APP_LAUNCH=YES'"
    ]
    , shell=True
)
```